# Chrome PDF inline viewing: contentscript.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null when viewing a PHP generated PDF

Tags: javascript, php, pdf-generation

Does someone have an idea why Chrome gives me the following error on the console when I open a PHP-generated PDF (with the FPDF library)? Below is a screenshot:

[image]

What is `contentscript.js` and why do I get this error message?

Could it be fixed somehow? Firefox doesn't return this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one of your Extensions in Google Chrome. This error is specific to you. Check your Chrome Extensions.

Comment: I have the following extensions in Chrome: `MeasureIt`, `NetBeans Connector`, `Page Ruler`, `TransOver`, how can I find which extension loads the `contentscript.js`?

Comment: Hmm i think it is MeasureIt

Comment: But this JS error don't block JavaScript which init on the page. This error can block only JS which call in the another Extension JS, but i'm not sure

Comment: Ok so it should be considered negligible, shouldn't it?